# Create HTML table using XSLT and XML, selecting a specific set of elements?

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to create a table in html from an XSLT file, but selecting only a specific group of nodes. For example in the following XML I wish to select all of the from and to child nodes where routename contains fco-dxb:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<flights
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="flights.xsd">

<flight flightid="1">
    <flightno>EK98</flightno>
    <callsign>UAE98</callsign>
    <airline>Emirates Airline</airline>

    <plane planeid="1">
        <name>Airbus A380-861</name>

        <registereddate>07-06-10</registereddate>
    </plane>


    <registration>3A6-EDJ</registration>
    <altitude height="feet">41000</altitude>
    <speed ratio="mph">564</speed>
    <distance unit="miles">erf</distance>

    <route>
    <routename>FCO-DXB</routename>
        <from>
            <iatacode>FCO</iatacode>
            <airport>Fiumicino</airport>
            <country>Italy</country>
            <city>Rome</city>
            <latitude>41.8044</latitude>
            <longitude>12.2508</longitude>
        </from>

        <to>
            <iatacode>DXB</iatacode>
            <airport>Dubai Intl</airport>
            <country>United Arab Emirates</country>
            <city>Dubai</city>
            <latitude>25.2528</latitude>
            <longitude>55.3644</longitude>
        </to>
    </route>

    <course bearing="degrees">154</course>

    <journey>
        <distance type="miles">2,697</distance> 
        <time>PT5H30M</time>
    </journey>

</flight>


<flight flightid="2">
    <flightno>BA283</flightno>
    <callsign>BAW283</callsign>
    <airline>British Airways</airline>

    <plane planeid="2">
        <name>Boeing 747-436</name>
        <registereddate>06-12-97</registereddate>
    </plane>


    <registration>3A6-EDJ</registration>
    <altitude height="feet">41000</altitude>
    <speed ratio="mph">564</speed>
    <distance unit="miles">erf</distance>

    <route>
    <routename>LHR-LAX</routename>
        <from>
            <iatacode>LHR</iatacode>
            <airport>Heathrow</airport>
            <country>England</country>
            <city>London</city>
            <latitude>51.4775</latitude>
            <longitude>0.4614</longitude>
        </from>

        <to>
            <iatacode>LAX</iatacode>
            <airport>Los Angeles International</airport>
            <country>United States of America</country>
            <city>L.A</city>
            <latitude>33.9471</latitude>
            <longitude>-118.4082</longitude>
        </to>
    </route>

    <course bearing="degrees">154</course>

    <journey>
        <distance type="miles">5,441 miles</distance> 
        <time>PT11H5M</time>
    </journey>

</flight>




</flights>
```

and output this in a table, here is my attempt in the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
        <xsl:element name="head">
            <xsl:element name="title">flights</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>


  <xsl:element name="body"> 
      <xsl:element name="table"><xsl:attribute name="border">1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:element name="tr">
          <xsl:element name="td">
            <xsl:element name="b">Title</xsl:element>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="td">
            <xsl:element name="b">Artist</xsl:element>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="td">
            <xsl:element name="b">Year</xsl:element>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="flights/flight/route[contains(text(), 'FCO-DXB')]" />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="from">
<xsl:element name="tr">
  <xsl:element name="td"><xsl:value-of select="iatacode"/></xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="td"><xsl:value-of select="airport"/></xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="td"><xsl:value-of select="country"/></xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="td"><xsl:value-of select="city"/></xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="to">
<xsl:element name="tr">
<xsl:element name="td"><xsl:value-of select="iatacode"/></xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="td"><xsl:value-of select="airport"/></xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="td"><xsl:value-of select="country"/></xsl:element>
  <xsl:element name="td"><xsl:value-of select="city"/></xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My goal is to eventually figure out how to pass parameters to the XSLT file so instead of hardcoding the contains text, I can pass it a parameter, but so far I would just like to know how to answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not say if there can be more than one routename with the same identifier. And if there are, they should be displayed in the same table or in a different table (one per match)?

I assume here that if there are multiple routenames with the same identifier, those are printed in the same table (correct me if this assumption is not right and I will change the code accordingly).

This is one way of doing what you are trying to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:param name="code"
           select="'FCO-DXB'" />

<xsl:template match="/flights">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>flights</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="flight/route[routename/. = $code]" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="route">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>IATA Code</b></td>
            <td><b>Airport</b></td>
            <td><b>Country</b></td>
            <td><b>City</b></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="from|to">
    <tr><xsl:apply-templates select="*" /></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="iatacode|airport|country|city">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, there will only be one routename with that text. Your code does what I want but it creates the table headers twice, I would like all the information to be in one table, is this possible? Thanks a lot, your code is a lot better than what I had! :)

Comment: That should work as expected. I also updated the solution to accept a param, which value could be set by the XSLT processor before parsing the XML (depending on the XSLT processor).

Comment: Thanks, I will try that! I added my complete XML file. Basically, I just want a table that contains all of the from data and to data for the selected routename. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the answer, so now it is adapted to the updated XML file.

Comment: The output that I get from the XSLT is the one that you described, so it must be something else on the PHP file.